# How to un-auto-awesome photos in Google+?

Tags: google-plus-photos

I made few nice high-resolution pictures but the evil "auto-awesome" made them into one ugly blurry low quality GIF.

I know there is a setting to disable "auto-awesome"ness but it was enabled on these pictures.

Is there a way to get the original pictures back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found an answer on  [Google Forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-plus-discuss/Se62OaBlDbk): the original pictures are still there.

I was just confused by the G+ UI: if I click on "Photos" all the pictures are there including the "awesome"d ones.